# Java Grep Library

Tags: java, grep

Is there any good, simple Java Grep Library? I'm not opposed to native code, or scripting, and I'll do it, but for my purposes, throughput is not a huge deal, and it would be nice to have it all in one tidy package.

UPDATE: Sorry. I know about java.regex, I just happen to be fairly busy and tired right now. What I'm looking for is something that efficiently combines java regex with going through a set of files and rewriting them. This wouldn't be too hard to write, I admit. I was just curious if that exists already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>I'm not aware of a sophisticated grep library</strike>strong text, but you are right: it's not hard to write.
I suggest a combination of `commons-io`  and `String.matches(someRegex)`:

```
public class Grep extends DirectoryWalker
{
    public Grep(){
        super();
    }

    public List clean(File startDirectory){
      List results = new ArrayList();
      walk(startDirectory, results);
      return results;
    }

    protected boolean handleDirectory(File directory,
                                      int depth, Collection results){
      // Decide if a (sub) directory will be handled for recursive search
      return true;
    }

    protected void handleFile(File file, int depth, Collection results)
    {
        LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
        try{
            while (it.hasNext()){
                String line = it.nextLine();
                if(line.matches("myRegEx")){
                    results.add(file);
                }
            }
         }
         finally {LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);}
    }
}
```

---

**Update** Marco pointed out `Unix4j` which is a quite interesting library which emulates the unix pipelining `|` with Java method chaining. `grep` is supported as well as `cat, cd, cut, echo, find, grep, head, ls, sed, sort, tail, uniq, wc, barges`.

Comment: That's more or less what I wrote in the end, except I used the very nice FileUtils.listFiles to filter stuff.

Answer (score 14):

Unix4j also implements a (pure java) grep command: http://www.unix4j.org

```
Unix4j.fromStrings("1:A", "2:B", "3:AB", "4:AC", "5:ABC").toFile("myFile.txt");
Unix4j.fromFile("myFile.txt").grep("AB").toStdOut();

>>>
3:AB 
5:ABC
```

**Disclosure:** I am one of the contributors to the unix4j project.

Answer (score 8):

yep. Grep4j - a grep lib for Unix environments, and you can also grep remotely easy : http://code.google.com/p/grep4j/

Comment: fyi, not a pure-java grep, it requires grep running on the machine.

Comment: @jk. Will you be able to tell me if it works with windows version of grep as well?

Comment: I had problem with using grep4j 1.8.7 coming from maven central repository. It used very old version of Lombok and my project used newest. When building project first time, some compilation errors occurred, which disappeared in re-builds.

Answer (score 4):

`String.matches(someRegex);`
Internally uses `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `Matcher`

Comment: You misspelled Pattern.  Fix it, this is the right answer. ;)