# Regex Search In Files using Java

Tags: java, regex, search

What I ask here should be pretty common but my intent is to figure out the best possible way to do it.

- I have a list of files(say n) within a directory - all of which have
  been categorized by extensions.
- I have a csv file containing Regex patterns(say m) which I want to look for in all those files of a particular type.
- I want to have a final output wherein I have a Regex pattern, file name,
  line and line number listed.

Here are the few questions I have about how I should approach this:

1. Is there a way where I could avoid m*n operations?
2. What's faster - reading the files, buffering content and storing each line in say in an array before a search for all regex expressions or should I be taking a regex pattern, read the file line by line and search as I parse without using up memory?
3. I figure that read/write operations are the most taxing - hence, I want to have 'n+1' reads(files, csv) and just a single write at the very end. Is my assumption and approach here correct?
4. Arrays, Lists, hashmaps, something else - any suggestion on what would be the best way to have the task done? I think parsing files would be the key to efficiency?
5. Any particular 'uncommon' Java APIs that I can make use of which reduce the code significantly?

I appreciate any insight/help with respect to this question.

.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222659/java-grep-library, but meh--why not just use grep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a simple working solution first, *then* optimize it.  That said, I think you might be able to do something like:

- Construct a composite regex from each of the individual regexes that you're searching for.  If they don't use capturing patterns, I suspect you could just do something like `"(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)"` and that'd be valid.  I'm not positive, though -- I've never been clear on how regex capturing groups work in when they're in different `|` branches.
- Use `Pattern.compile(regexString)` to precompile the regex so it's not rebuilt more than once.
- Use Guava's [`Files.toString(File, Charset)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#toString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to just slurp each file all at once.  If you're that keen on doing it line-by-line, use [`Files.readLines(File, Charset)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to get a `List<String>`.  You might even use the full-blown callback-based `Files.readLines(File, Charset, LineProcessor)` to avoid having the whole file in memory at once.
- Use the compiled `Pattern` to match against the target file -- you'll probably need to use the `Matcher` to identify where exactly the match was, and which pattern was matched.

Comment: Composite regex would not work for me since I wanted the output to also capture the matching regex pattern. Or is there a way?

Comment: ...There might be, but it'll be tricky.  Super tricky.  At this point, I'd recommend going ahead with the `n * m` solution that matches each pattern independently, and then see if that's fast enough for your needs.  If not, go ahead and attempt the deep hackery -- probably by figuring out which pattern is the "outer pattern" corresponding to "regex number ___."