# i want to search for "MAN-xxxx-xxxxx" in a text file using regular expression.Can anyone help me this?

Tags: java, regex

i want to search for `MAN-xxxx-xxxxx` in a text file using regular expression.Can anyone help me this??

Comment: What do the `x`'s represent?  numbers?  letters?  What have you tried?

Comment: try `MAN-(\w{4})-(\w{5})`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen x is a number

Comment: Did you tried to write a Regex ? DId you tried to match the String to this Regex ? Provide something or produce it before asking.

Comment: MAN-(\w{4})-(\w{5}) .it is showing this error:Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) .@Jens

Comment: I gave you a working solution below, did you bother to have a look at it?

Comment: Because in Java you need to escape `\\` in a String.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Search In Files using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169379/regex-search-in-files-using-java)

Comment: Sorry @Tim Biegeleisen. The solution that you gave worked fine for me.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find below working code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "This cat MAN-1243-23445 placed  OK? This cat MAN-1243-23445 placed  OK? This cat MAN-1243-23445 placed  OK? This cat MAN-1243-23445 placed  OK?This cat MAN-1243-23445 placed  OK? This cat MAN-1243-23445 placed  OK?";
        String pattern = "(MAN-\\d{4}-\\d{5})"; // The 2 and 3 match only for digit
        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        //first Occurrence
        /*if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group() );
        }else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }*/
        //For all the occurrence
        while(m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wow it works.Even i tried the same code but it was giving the whole line from the text file.I think there was an issue with the pattern.But now in your program it works fine.Thank you

Comment: I have not handled that case, you can handle it in if condition.

Comment: if there are two occurrences of the pattern the above program wont print both the occurrences

Comment: no, In this case you can get via m.group[1] ... something like that.

Comment: you can debug matcher object values.

Comment: If i know there are only two occurrences then i can use m.group(1).   If the string is a text file then we won't know how many occurrences will be available.In general how can we write it??

Comment: then you can check the length of group, can you please accept the answer

Comment: how to check the length of the group

Comment: By using while loop you will get all the occurrences.

Comment: Please find the updated code you will get all the occurrences it this case.